# dx Fontawesome Editors-ext button doesn't work on front-end

Tags: joomla-3.x, troubleshooting

There's a component called [dx FontAwesome button](http://extensions.joomla.org/extension/dx-fontawesome-button) that is used for inserting Font Awesome elements into articles via the editors-ext button.

On the back-end it's working fine but not on the front-end. The button appears, but in the modal window it gives an error message: 404 Component not found.

- /administrator/components/com_dxfontawesome folder was created with all the necessary files
- /component/com_dxfontawesome folder was created **but it's empty**
- /plugins/editors-ext/dxfabutton folder contains *dxfabutton.php* and *dxfabutton.xml* files

I tried the following but **couldn't resolve** the issue.

1. Following to the core **com_media** I put a new
   *dxfontawesome.php* file into /component/com_dxfontawesome folder and add the following code:

   ```
   require_once JPATH_COMPONENT_ADMINISTRATOR.'/dxfontawesome.php';
   ```

   Then I got a new error message: 0 Invalid controller: name='',
   format=''
2. I modified the *dxfabutton.php* at line #43:

   ```
   $app = JFactory::getApplication();
   if( $app->isAdmin() ) $link ="";
   else $link = "administrator/";
   $link .= 'index.php?option=com_dxfontawesome&amp;view=dxfontawesome&amp;layout=fa_selector&amp;tmpl=component&amp;editor='. $name;
   ```

After that it partially works but after clicking the font selector button the system asks to login into the back-end...

If I log into the back-end and then go back to the front end, the font awesome selector works, but it is not a real solution for our users with publisher permission.

**Any help** would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

> /component/com_dxfontawesome folder was created but it's empty

Taking a look at the install archive of that component, that folder shouldn't be empty. Try to reinstall it.

If that doesn't help copy the files from the install archive from /packages/com_dxfontawesome.zip/site/ to /component/com_dxfontawesome/

[image]

Comment: The install archive doesn't have site folder.

Comment: It does, see the screenshot in my updated answer

Comment: Okay, I'm corresponding with the author too and he updated the package. Installing the new version now the /components/com_dxfontawesome folder is really not empty but the system asks to login into the back-end when you try to use this editor button on front-end.

Comment: I also asked the author about this behavior but no answer till now.

Comment: The author resolved this issue in the last dx fa button package: [link](https://dibuxo.com/en/joomlacms/dx-fa-button/dx-fa-button-2)